# How Can I Allow the User to Remove an Object From a .txt file Using Json through Python

Tags: python, json, thonny

## Summarization of the problem

I made this address book that dumps user input onto a .txt file, I want to be able to let the user erase a person saved in the address book(the .txt file) if they wish to.  How should I go about this? Basically I just want it to be wiped from the .txt file without having to manually do it myself
and without getting rid of the other names and info

## What I've tried

Heres some code I entered into my program to try to allow the user to carry out the task of removing someone but it would run smoothly but then when I went to go check the .txt file the person and their info still remained.

```
if input("would you like to remove someone from the registry?('Yes' or 'No')") ==  "Yes":
    who_delete = input("Who would you like to remove?")
del who_delete
```

(I entered the code above under the book = {} line on the code listed below the line.)

---

```
#current code
import json

book = {}

Name = input("Enter a name")

book[Name] = {
"Address": input("Enter an adress"),
"Phone": input("Enter a phone number"),
}

s=json.dumps(book, indent=2)
with open("C://Users//user//OneDrive//Desktop//Library//Coding and Programming Projects//Self Projects//Address Book//addressbook.txt", "a") as f:
    f.write(s)
```

Expected Result: To remove an object from the .txt file through the shell while running the program without having to manually do it on the .txt file

Actual Result: The object was not removed from the .txt file

Comment: `del book([who_delete])` should have raised an error. please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pop` to remove a key and it's value from a dictionary. In this case `book.pop(Name)` should remove the name and it's details.

It's probably also wise to check that the name that the user inputs is in the dictionary (and that it is spelt correctly) otherwise you will get an error when trying to pop a non-existent key. You could do this something like

```
input_response = input("would you like to remove someone from the registry?('Yes' or 'No')")
if input_response == "Yes":
    who_delete = input("Who would you like to remove?")
    if who_delete in books:
        books.pop(who_delete)
    else:
        print(f'Name {who_delete} not in books, please choose a valid key from {list(books.keys())}')
```

Comment: Wouldn't the code be entered like this?:book.pop(who_delete). This gives me an error as well: book.pop(who_delete)
KeyError: 'Samuel White'

Comment: This will happen if you don't check first if the name is in the dictionary you should check this first via `if Name in books`, and only call `pop` if this is true, if not you can list the names that are actually in the dictionary to see if for example you've spelt on incorrectly i.e. "Samuel White" vs "Sam White" see additional comment above.

Comment: could you give me an example? How would I implement it into this code:          `if input("would you like to remove someone from the registry?('Yes' or 'No')") ==  "Yes":
    who_delete = input("Who would you like to remove?")
del who_delete`

Comment: You should nest the `if who_delete in books` to be called if `if input_response == "Yes"`, as show

Comment: is there a way I can share my code with you so that it is formatted properly? I have the code and put it what you sent me but it still does not remove the person from the .txt file

Comment: Not other than in the main section that I know of. I am assuming that after you run this code you're re-saving the text file before you're checking that the item has been removed. Is this correct, are you re-saving it? If not you will need to do so otherwise the item will not be removed.

Comment: It saves by itself I thought? After I run the program and insert a name and go to check the .txt file its always there and when I close it and re open it it is still there.  By saving it do you mean manually saving the .txt file each time I make changes through the python shell?

Answer (score 0):

`open(path, "a")` will append (add) to the file. Assuming your file is json, you need to first read the content with something like:

```
with open(path, "r") as f:
    content = json.load(f)
```

then alter content, removing things you don't want, and finally write back to the file:

```
with open(path, "w") as f:
    json.dump(content, f)
```

Comment: this gave me the error:  
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 6 column 2 (char 95)

Comment: This is probably because, if you kept appending to it, your file will not contain valid json. Try with a fresh file containing just {} for example (if your content is a dictionary).

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean by dictionary in this sense.  Do you want me to remove the append part?

Comment: You cannot append to a json file and still have a valid json file.